# There are no sections of blowup $Bl_0(\mathbb{A}^2)$ of affine plane at the origin

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, blowup, projective-varieties

Let $p:Bl_0(\mathbb{A}^2) \to \mathbb{A}^2$ be blowup of plane
at the origin. Is there a geometric reason why there
are no sections $s: \mathbb{A^2} \to Bl_0(\mathbb{A^2})$, that is
no maps to vareties with $p \circ s= id$ on affine plane $\mathbb{A^2}$.

Where I'm trying to get to is: in [this comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/746448/total-space-of-line-bundle-mathcalo1-same-as-blow-up-of-plane) by Zhen Lin used this
recognizing the total space of the tautological line bundle $O(-1)$
on $\mathbb{P}^1$ to be identical to the blowup of affine plane at the origin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one simple geometric reason: Consider any two distinct lines $L_1, L_2$ through the origin in $\newcommand{\AA}{\mathbb{A}}\AA^2$. The proper transforms of these two lines under the blowup at the origin are two *non-intersecting* lines in $\newcommand{\Bl}{\operatorname{Bl}}\Bl_0(\AA^2)$. If there were a section $s\colon \AA^2 \to \Bl_0(\AA^2)$ of the blowup map, then it would have to map each of these lines to its proper transform, because the image of a connected space under a continuous map is connected, and regular maps are continuous. But this is impossible, because this forces $s(0, 0)$ to have two different values.

Comment: a beautiful argument. Do you maybe know how far the original claim can 
be genalized? Is it in generally true that if $X$ is a variety and 
$Z \subset X$ a 
subvariety and we blow up $p:Bl_Z(X) \to X$ in $Z$ there is no section
$s: X \to Bl_Z(X)$? If $X$ smooth we can work locally and use similar argument
as for affine plane to show that such section not exist. But what about
weird cases where eg $X$ has singular locus $Z$ and we blow it up or
if $X$ don't have lines thrrough $z \in X$ and we blow up this point.
Can blow ups of such pathological constructions have sections?

Comment: Yeah, same argument should work whenever $X$ is smooth. For more general schemes $X$, it's not obvious off the top of my head why there couldn't be a section of the blowup map, though I strongly suspect the statement is true in a lot more generality than just smooth varieties.

Comment: @IsaktheXI I thought about it a bit more and was able to prove the statement for arbitrary blowups of schemes. I've written up the proof here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3906612/section-of-blowup-map-of-schemes

Comment: I thank you for your effort!